# Drop database if model changes in EF Core without migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

In previous version of entity framework, one could recreate the database if the model changes, using some of the classes DropDatabseIfModelChanges and other related classes. 
In EF7 or EF Core i don't know how to do that. Run the migrations some times give problems and in the beginning of the project i need to change the models constantly.

Answer (score 7):

There's currently no easy way to implement `DropDatabseIfModelChanges` in EFCore. EF6 worked by storing a snapshot of your model in the `__MigrationHistory` table and comparing it to the current model. No such information is stored by `EnsureCreated` in EFCore.

To mimic the behavior in EFCore, you could manually store a hash of the model whenever you create the database in EFCore, check the hash on startup, and drop and re-create the database if it has changed.

```cs
var currentHash = MyHashingFunction(db.Model);

if (db.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().Exists()
    && !db.Set<ModelHash>().Any(mh => mh.Value == currentHash))
{
    // Drop if changed
    db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
}

if (db.Database.EnsureCreated())
{
    // Insert hash if created
    db.Add(new ModelHash { Value = currentHash });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: is it still the recommended workaround on the recent version of EF Core? Version 2.0 I suppose

Comment: Yes. There haven't been any changes to this area in version 2.0.

Comment: Too bad, it's really a nice to have feature when doing TDD, since models changes often on development. I don't want to tweak migrations everytime

Comment: GetService does not exist on "db"

Comment: is db.Model.GetHashCode() ok ?

Comment: also EnsureDeleted does not exist

Comment: `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;`

Comment: No, `Model.GetHashCode()` isn't implemented.

Comment: How to implement the MyHashingFunction method? Any sample?

Comment: @Nico Here's a quick and dirty approach: `SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(model.ToDebugString()))`

Comment: @bricelam what's inside this ToDebugString() method then?

Comment: A string representation of *most* of the model. Thus, it will work *most* of the time. Some obscure changes may not be detected.

Comment: (It's an extension method in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal` namespace.)

Comment: @bricelam thanks. since i'll be using it only in Development/Testing environment, the accuracy is not gonna be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Initializers don't exist in [EF Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3042). Instead you can call EnsureCreated (and possibly EnsureDeleted):

```
public class MyCountriesContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  public MyCountriesContext()
  {
    Database.EnsureCreated();
  }

  public DbSet<Visit> Visits { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.Entity<Visit>().Key(v => v.Id);

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  }
}
```

See https://wildermuth.com/2015/03/17/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_3_-_EF7